# Is there any way to start a stream in a Phonon Media Object from an arbitrary point?

Tags: c++, qt, phonon

I'm writing an application to listen to podcasts in Qt 4.8.1 on Mac OS X. Right now, I'm setting my `MediaObject` to use the enclosure URL from the podcast's RSS item, like so:

```
mediaObj->setCurrentSource(Phonon::MediaSource(QUrl(idx.data(Metadata::Enclosure).toString())));
```

Note: `idx` is a `QModelIndex` that corresponds to the `QStandardItem` within my model that the user clicked on in a `QTreeView` widget.

I've got two problems right now, though.

1. Whenever I pause the stream and start it again, it starts from the beginning. Not so helpful. :-(
2. If I use my `Phonon::SeekSlider` widget to skip ahead to a part of the stream I haven't yet buffered, I'm getting bounced back to the beginning of the stream.

My (potentially flawed) thinking is that if I could figure out a way to get `mediaObj` to start playing from a specific time in the stream, I could fix both these problems. And so, I've tried this:

```
void BrodCastMainWin::pauseStream()
{
    //save the "left off at" point in the stream
    qDebug() << "current time is:" << currentTime;
    qDebug() << "Saving place at" << currentTimeString
             << "in item" << nowPlaying.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
    //need to use QModelIndex for setData()
    QModelIndex nowPlayingHandle = nowPlaying;
    feed.setData(nowPlayingHandle, QVariant(currentTime), Metadata::LeftOffAt);
    //pause the stream
    mediaObj->pause();
}

void BrodCastMainWin::playStream()
{
    //seek to the "left off at" point in the stream
    qDebug() << "Trying to seek to" << convertTime(nowPlaying.data(Metadata::LeftOffAt).toLongLong())
             << "in item" << nowPlaying.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
    mediaObj->seek(nowPlaying.data(Metadata::LeftOffAt).toLongLong());
    //play the file
    mediaObj->play();
}
```

Note: `currentTime` is the time as of the last `tick()` signal `mediaObj` emitted. I tried to get this data using the `currentTime()` method within `mediaObj`, and it didn't work. But that's a battle for another day. Similarly, `currentTimeString` is the same info in a human-readable format.

Alas, it doesn't work :-(. This is what happens with that code when I play the stream:

```
current time is: 32153 
Saving place at "00:32" in item "Leo Laporte - The Tech Guy 867" 
switching button to 'play'
```

Groovy. But when I try to play again:

```
Trying to seek to "00:32" in item "Leo Laporte - The Tech Guy 867" 
Playing/Loading/Buffering; switching button to 'pause' 
current time is: 0 
Saving place at "00:00" in item "Leo Laporte - The Tech Guy 867" 
switching button to 'play' 
Trying to seek to "00:00" in item "Leo Laporte - The Tech Guy 867" 
Playing/Loading/Buffering; switching button to 'pause'
```

I'm totally confused. It seems like I'm trying to make Phonon behave in a way it doesn't want to. **My fear is that this seems like a long-standing problem with the Phonon module, and I might have to implement the stream some other way.** Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it appears I got too fancy. I'm using a single button for play/pause. I simply had to change this:

```
void BrodCastMainWin::handleMediaState(Phonon::State state, Phonon::State)
{
    switch (state)
    {
    case Phonon::PlayingState:
    case Phonon::LoadingState:
    case Phonon::BufferingState:
        qDebug() << "Playing/Loading/Buffering; switching button to 'pause'";
        //If we're playing, the button should pause
        ui->playPauseButton->setIcon(QIcon(":/assets/stock_media-pause.svg"));
        connect(ui->playPauseButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                this, SLOT(pauseStream()));
        break;
    case Phonon::PausedState:
    case Phonon::StoppedState:
        qDebug() << "switching button to 'play'";
        //if we're paused, the button should play
        ui->playPauseButton->setIcon(QIcon(":/assets/stock_media-play.svg"));
        connect(ui->playPauseButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                this, SLOT(playStream()));
    case Phonon::ErrorState:
        //additionally, if there's an error, do error handling.
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

...to this:

```
void BrodCastMainWin::handleMediaState(Phonon::State state, Phonon::State)
{
    switch (state)
    {
    case Phonon::PlayingState:
        qDebug() << "Playing/Loading/Buffering; switching button to 'pause'";
        //If we're playing, the button should pause
        ui->playPauseButton->setIcon(QIcon(":/assets/stock_media-pause.svg"));
        connect(ui->playPauseButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                this, SLOT(pauseStream()));
        break;
    case Phonon::PausedState:
        qDebug() << "switching button to 'play'";
        //if we're paused, the button should play
        ui->playPauseButton->setIcon(QIcon(":/assets/stock_media-play.svg"));
        connect(ui->playPauseButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                this, SLOT(playStream()));
        break;
    case Phonon::ErrorState:
        //additionally, if there's an error, do error handling.
        break;
    case Phonon::LoadingState:
    case Phonon::BufferingState:
    case Phonon::StoppedState:
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Of course, I'm eventually going to want to handle those other states, too. But this solves the first of my problems. The other problem will probably have to wait until another day.